# Torch with CUDA10

Tags: machine-learning, torch, luarocks

I am trying to install torch with cuda10 on  my raspberry pi. I am following the following github thread ( answer of nagadomi:
https://github.com/torch/cutorch/issues/834

Following all his steps still when I run ./install.sh
I get the following error

> make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'exe/luajit-rocks/luajit-2.1/src/lib_ffi.c', needed by 'exe/luajit-rocks/luajit-2.1/vmdef.lua'.  Stop.
>   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:212: exe/luajit-rocks/luajit-2.1/CMakeFiles/luajit-static.dir/all] Error 2
>   make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
>   ./install.sh: line 107: /home/pi/torch/install/bin/luarocks: No such file or directory
>   Installing common Lua packages
>   ./install.sh: line 111: /home/pi/torch/install/bin/luarocks: No such file or directory

I have now spent a week just trying to setup torch with CUDA.
Basically I need cutorch library and it is not installing from `luarocks install cutorch

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Do you have an NVIDIA GPU in your raspberry pi? If not, what is the point of using CUDA on it?

Comment: I wan to use  a humanflow model. It have a cutorch library required which I need to install

Comment: So cuda requires nvidia gpu? I'm sorry i have no idea of Cuda

Comment: Yes, CUDA requires a NVIDIA GPU, that's why I point this out to you, it won't work on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I want to use this pretrained model https://github.com/anuragranj/humanflow/blob/master

Comment: Can I do that on raspberry or any alternative available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CUDA allows to write programs that can utilize the power of NVIDIA GPUs. It provides a framework to allows developers to write code that can be executed in parallel on the thousands of cores available in modern GPUs. On a RaspberryPI you may not have a NVIDIA GPU, so even if you install CUDA correctly, there is no hardware it can work with.

You could add a Tensor Processing Unit (TPU) to a Raspberry Pi to accelerate machine learning workloads. Googles Coral Edge TPU is a popular option for this. The Coral USB Accelerator is a small hardware device that contains a TPU and can be connected to a Raspberry Pis USB port.